# Microservice dependency architecture design pattern - How do I practically organize my dependencies?

Tags: architecture, microservices, api-gateway

### I am a beginner to microservice architecture and ask myself a question to the following scenario:

Given my frontend makes an authorized request to at least 2 distinct services. E.g.: The request should book a product for a particular user. It is probably good practice to organize this request through an API-Gateway. The Product-Service relies on the User-Service to know which user wants its product.

1. How should the dependency be organized? Should the API-GW call the User-Service then pass the info to the Product-Service or should only the Product-Service be called and handle the relation to the User-Service itself.
2. How would you organize the authorization in this vanilla system? Will there be an Auth-Service that is called each time from each service when information is accessed or should it be implemented differently.

Please share your knowledge on this system design. I could think about different ways to do it but I am looking for a best practice approach and would like to know its benefits.

Comment: Please feel free to share with me any other crucial advice you have when building such a microservice architecture for example regarding code sharing.

Comment: How are your users authenticated?, does the user server, does this service also authenticate users? i.e. play the role of an Authorization server or Identity provider? Your front end Is is it public or confidential client? (iSPA or server side MPA)?
How are you securing your microservers? (MTLS, tokens etc..)

Answer (score 0):

I have designed, solved and implemented answer to this problem several times.

1. User details is fundamental to we application. In well architected web applications, this is a service on itself which gives all the users, their profile details.
2. For authentication look at the JWT token. JWT token works on a timeout, provides complete AUTHZ/AUTHN details for the user. This gets passed to every service invocation.
3. Always ensure that you have a central token provider service that adheres to OAUTH2 standard.

Do let me know, if you need some more details. Happy to help, DM me.